# How to convert multi type NSObject property into C# in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, nsobject

In my objective-c `interface` I have a `property` like this

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSObject<LSMAHandler, LSMAHandlerPincode, LSMAHandlerRegister> *agentHandler;
```

How can I convert this into C# in my xamarin.iOS.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is an equivalent of this in C#, but I can tell you what it means. `agentHandler` can be of any type that inherits `NSObject` and implements all three of those interfaces.

Comment: You can define it as [binding-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows#binding-properties) with the type NSObject.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, this is a way of Objective-C indicate this is a type that inherits from NSObject and conforms the three protocols. This protocols for C# will be simple interfaces.

C# directly does not support this (I believe), but you can create your own type based on the information above.

Let's call our new class **AgentHandler**

```
public class AgentHandler: NSObject, LSMAHandler, LSMAHandlerPincode, LSMAHandlerRegister
{

}
```

The above will be the definition of your `class`. You will also need to implement the interfaces.

Now your property would be something like:

```
public AgentHandler AgentHandler {get; private set;}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: But how can I define it in ApiDefinition.cs?